# Código de PHP para actualizar datos en DB no funciona

Tags: php, sqlite3

Tengo una aplicación que es para manejar favoritos (mis páginas de internet favoritas) y el código encargado de actualizar los usuarios no me actualiza, solo me cambia el nombre por un 0 y el resto lo deja como está. Les pongo unas imágenes y díganme si necesitan que suba algo más.

Está es la tabla para gestionar los usuarios, el 3<sup>er</sup>, 4º y 5º usuario muestran lo que les decía:

[image: Tabla gestion usuarios]

Y éste es el código encargado de actualizar los usuarios:

```
<?php

session_start();

$db = new SQLite3('favoritos.db');

$usuarioantiguo = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];

$resultado = $db->query("UPDATE usuarios SET usuario='".$usuario."' AND contrasena='".$contrasena."' AND nombre='".$nombre."' AND apellido='".$apellido."' AND edad=".$edad." WHERE usuario='".$usuarioantiguo."'");

$db->close();

//Vuelvo a gestionusuarios.php
echo "
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='0;url=gestionusuarios.php'>
    </head>
</html>
";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fallo ocurre porque hay un error en tu SQL. Los campos que se actualizan no van separados por `AND` sino por coma (`,`). La sintaxis de un `UPDATE` debería ser así:

```
UPDATE nombre_de_tabla
SET columna1 = valor1, columna2 = valor2 ..., columnaN = valorN
WHERE [condición];
```

Al poner un `AND` lo que estás haciendo es asignar al campo `usuario` el valor de la operación lógica:

```
'".$usuario."' AND contrasena='".$contrasena."' AND nombre='".$nombre."' AND apellido='".$apellido."' AND edad=".$edad." WHERE usuario='".$usuarioantiguo."'"
```

---

Tienes que cambiar el código para que sea algo como esto:

```
$resultado = $db->query("UPDATE usuarios SET usuario='".$usuario."', contrasena='".$contrasena."', nombre='".$nombre."', apellido='".$apellido."', edad=".$edad." WHERE usuario='".$usuarioantiguo."'");
```

y entonces el `UPDATE` debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Aparte de eso, deberías usar consultas parametrizadas: ahora mismo el `UPDATE` sufre problemas de inyección de SQL. Si la página está disponible en internet, alguien podría inyectar valores maliciosos y las consecuencias podrían ser terribles en tu base de datos (p.e.: imagina si alguien pasa esto como valor para el campo usuario: `'; DROP TABLE usuarios; --`).

Comment: Mil gracias Alvaro Montoro, en realidad es un ejercicio, no lo estoy haciendo para subirlo a internet, pero igual agradezco la correccion, siempre es bueno aprender algo nuevo =D